# How do I get some JavaScript/jQuery to run in sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML file which contains two divisions. One has id 'welcome' and the other is named 'welcome_distort'.

With jQuery imported, I have a seperate js file which contains some code that operates on these divs.

```
$("#welcome").fadeTo(50,0.1);
$("#welcome").fadeTo(10,1.0);
$("#welcome").fadeTo(10,0.1);
$("#welcome").fadeTo(10,1.0);
$("#welcome").fadeTo(1000,0.0);

$("#welcome_distort").css({opacity:"1.0"});
```

All the fadeTo() commands work in sequence. What I then want to happen is the css() command to come after these fadeTo()s. In reality, the operation on welcome_distort takes place at the same time as the first operation on welcome. My question is: how do I get the .css() operation to run after the last .fadeTo().

Many Thanks,
John

Answer (score 2):

fadeto has a callback option, that runs after the animation is complete. My code is grabbed from: http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo

```
$('#welcome').fadeTo(1000,0.0, function() {
      $("#welcome_distort").css({opacity:"1.0"});
    });
```